# Write a function named is_two that takes in a variable and returns True or False if the input is the number 2 or the string "2"

Tags: python

I'm having some issues with getting my code to validate the "2" as a True value. Just need some help with seeing exactly why that is?

> Write a function named ˚ that takes in a variable and returns True or False if the input is the number `2` or the string `"2"`

```
def is_two(x):
    return x == 2
    

assert is_two(2) == True
assert is_two("2") == True
assert is_two(3) == False
assert is_two(10) == False
assert is_two("two") == False
print("Exercise 4 is complete.")``
```

Comment: What issues are you having? You never compare it with the string.

Comment: Yuo can use `or` to combine two conditions like this.

Comment: Is JavaScript your background? There your function would be fine. In python however `2 == "2"` returns `False`

Answer (score 4):

As @Barmar has hinted in his comments, if you want a `True` result for either `2` or `"2"`, you can use `or` to test this as follows:

```
def is_two(x):
    return x == 2 or x == "2"
```

An alternative is to create a `tuple` containing the two target results `2` and `"2"` and to test whether `x` is `in` this `tuple`:

```
def is_two(x):
    return x in (2, "2")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that equality comparisons are generally type-aware; `2 != "2"`.  (There are some funny cases, e.g. `True == 1`, but that's not relevant here.)

I'd suggest:

```
def is_two(x):
    return str(x) == "2"
```

In the case where `x` is a `str` already, converting it to a `str` is a no-op; in the case where it's an `int`, `2` will become `"2"`, so the comparison will return `True`.

Comment: Correct me  if I am wrong but won't this return True for whatever custom class you write that has its `__str__` return "2"?

Comment: Yup!  Note that custom classes can do tricky things with `__eq__` and `__hash__` as well.  :)

Comment: Good point. Would it therefore be technically safer to reverse the arguments?

Comment: Making this function "secure" such that it's impossible for malicious code to fool it is a bit out of scope for an intro level assignment IMO.  :)  Dealing with malicious input, especially at the API level, is its whole own topic, and for most code it's not something you need to worry about unless you're doing something really sketchy like using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a few line to your code:

```py
def is_two(x):
  if isinstance(x, str) and x.isdigit():
    x = int(x)
  if x == 2:
    return True
  return False
assert is_two(2) == True
assert is_two("2") == True
assert is_two(3) == False
assert is_two(10) == False
assert is_two("two") == False
```

If you run the abovementioned code, you will see all the assertions will be validated.

##### Explanation

You need to use `isinstance` in order to check whether the `x` variable is a string or not. Then if it's a string, you need to make sure it is a number, but in the form of a string. Then by using `int` function, you parse this string into a digit(integer).